# Use CASE statement to check if column exists in table - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I'm using a **SQL server** statement embedded in some other C# code; and simply want to check if a column exists in my table.

If the column (`ModifiedByUSer` here) does exist then I want to return a **1** or a **true**; if it doesn't then I want to return a **0** or a **false** (or something similar that can be interpreted in C#).

I've got as far as using a CASE statement like the following:

```
SELECT cast(case WHEN EXISTS (select ModifiedByUser from Tags) 
            THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
            END as bit)
```

But if the ModifiedByUser doesn't exist then I'm getting an `invalid column name`, instead of the return value.

I've also considered:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Tags' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ModifiedByUser')
  BEGIN // Do something here to return a value
  END
```

But don't know how to conditionally return a value/bool/bit based on the result.
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: As you've discovered, it's better to add an answer below the question, to maintain the standard question-answer format. Thanks for adding it!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Final answer was a combination of two of the above (I've upvoted both to show my appreciation!):

```
select case 
   when exists (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM Sys.columns c 
      WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Tags') 
         AND c.name = 'ModifiedByUserId'
   ) 
   then 1 
   else 0 
end
```

Comment: Since the original post mentioned using something like C# to work with the result, I would suggest also casting the value to a bit in the sql. That way C# can actually work with the returned value as a bool.

Answer (score 16):

```
select case
         when exists (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Tags' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ModifiedByUser')
         then 0
         else 1
       end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems to be always returning 1, whether the column is present or not.

Comment: I've combined your answer with the one below and it seems to work: `select case when exists (SELECT 1 FROM Sys.columns c WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Tags') AND c.name = 'ModifiedByUserId') then 1 else 0 end`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM ...
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
        FROM sys.columns c
        WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Tags')
            AND c.name = 'ModifiedByUser'
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
SELECT *
FROM ...
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
        FROM sys.columns c
        WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Tags')
            AND c.name = 'ModifiedByUser'
    )
```

Comment: @table_name like 'dbo.table1'

Comment: How do I use this?  Sorry not familiar with SQL and this is hard to get my head around.

Comment: I've combined your answer with the one above and it seems to work: `select case when exists (SELECT 1 FROM Sys.columns c WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Tags') AND c.name = 'ModifiedByUserId') then 1 else 0 end`

Answer (score 1):

You can check in the system 'table column mapping' table

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM Sys.Columns c
  JOIN Sys.Tables t ON c.Object_Id = t.Object_Id
 WHERE upper(t.Name) = 'TAGS'
   AND upper(c.NAME) = 'MODIFIEDBYUSER'
```

Comment: Thanks but this is giving me an **Invalid column name `Table_Name`** for line 4.  Any ideas why?

Comment: @WheretheresaWill .. My Bad.. I have change and corrected the query.. now check